# Python 3 - printing rows in csv reader object results in a single character on each line

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to migrate some code from Python 2 to Python 3 and cannot figure out why it is printing one character at a time as if it is reading the file as one long string.

I have been looking into it and maybe a need to use `newline=''` when opening the file?

But how can I do that when using `urlopen()`?

```
import csv
import urllib.request
url = "http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

csvfile = ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8')
csvfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in csvfile:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
csvfile = ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8')
```

to

```
csvfile = ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8').split('\r')
```

Comment: Is \r the best thing to use?  Would that only work on Windows?

Comment: Have no ideas about Windows. Checked only for Linux. But we have obvious separator '\r' in this file. So it should work everywhere.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. And an explanation would help. Why does encoding make the csv module read character by character?